# Knockout validation on hasfocus binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an issue with the knockout validation on hasfocus binding.

I am trying to validate the control and show an error message when the control looses focus. but when the form loads itself rule is getting triggered and it shows the error message.

is there anyway to tell on load of the form or when we initialize the rules not to fire?

```
self.lostfocus = ko.observable(false);
self.lostfocus.extend({ NoBlankValidationlookup: { params: { control: self }, message: "Search Text cannot be empty"} });

ko.validation.rules['NoBlankValidationlookup'] = {
validator: function (val, params)
{
    ////if the control looses focus then validate.
    if (!val)
    {
        if (params.control.Value().length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
},
message: 'Please enter at least 0 characters.'
};

//HTML
<div id="Div1" class="vm" style="display: block !important; text-align: left" data-bind="validationMessage:lostfocus"></div>
```

Please adivce.

Answer (score 0):

use isModified(false) with your validated observable on form load.

so run something like this:

```
self.lostfocus.isModified(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add valueUpdate to specify when to call your rules, for instance:

```
   self.lostfocus.extend({valueUpdate: 'afterKeyDown', NoBlankValidationlookup:
      { params: { control: self }, message: "Search Text cannot be empty"} });
```

Comment: The problem would be if user just tabs out of the control without key down any characters also I want to show the error message. So valueUpdate will not help right?

Comment: right I see. In that case I think binding a function on the inputs blur event would work e.g, data-bind="event: {blur: (function name here) }"